# Expectation of $E(\frac{(X+Y)^4}{X-Y})$ where X,Y are standard normal distributed

Tags: random-variables, variance, expected-value

For my exam preparation I'm currently stuck at this task. Let X,Y be i.i.d and standard normal distributed variables. Calculate $E\left(\frac{(X+Y)^4}{X-Y}\right)$. So I have

- $E(X)=E(Y)=0$ and $Var(X)=Var(Y)=1$
- $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)=0$ and $E(XY)=0$
- $E(X^2)=1$ since $E(X^2)=Var(X)+(E(X))^2 = 1 + 0^2 = 1$
- Product of i.i.d is again i.i.d

Now I try to break the initial expression down, so I can put the values above into the expression:
$$E\left(\frac{(X+Y)^4}{X-Y}\right) = E((X+Y)^4)E\left(\frac{1}{X-Y}\right)=(E(X+Y))^4E\left(\frac{1}{X-Y}\right)=0$$ which does not seems to be correct.
Thansk for tips/adivece.

Comment: This expectation does not exist.

Comment: $X-Y$ is again a Normal variable, and mean of the reciprocal of this variable does not exist because the corresponding integral does not converge absolutely.